# Android Studio "Import class" action adds fully qualified name

Tags: configuration, intellij-idea, android-studio

Using Android Studio, when I type the name of a class which I have no import for and use the "Import class" action (using either ALT-ENTER or choosing the "Import class" action from the CTRL-A menu), it simply adds the package name in front of my class.

For example,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

becomes

```
android.content.Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Is there any way to have the "Import class" action add an import to the file by default instead of adding the fully qualified name like this?

I am quite certain it used to work as I describe. Unfortunately, I cannot tell what changed since then and I would like to avoid reinstalling the IDE and reconfiguring everything to my liking.

**My configuration**

In the Intentions settings, the option "Imports / Replace Qualified Name with Import" is **checked**.

In the Editor settings, the "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" option is **unchecked** and "Optimize imports on the fly" is **checked**

Comment: I'm coming from eclipse and I hate AS way of appending fully qualified name whenever I use its code completion!

Comment: You see the same behavior so this is not just a misconfiguration on my part?

Comment: yep, but I think there must be a way to change it, otherwise it is totally unusable as it messed up with properly imported code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I did the same thing.  It took me a while to realize, but I had checked the
 (menu) File --> Settings (in dialog) Code Style --> Java --> Imports (tab) --> "Use fully qualified class names" checkbox.

As soon as I un-checked that, Android studio stopped fully qualifying the class names that did not (yet) have import statements for.  An example was when I was trying to cast to TextView in my code and it auto fully qualified it.  Now it just adds it as an import at the top!

Note I am using Android Studio 0.5.9 in case my path to the checkbox is different than yours.  Good Luck!
Paul