# Android studio imports full package name in the code?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I have a problem with android studio and I've tried to change the settings but it doesn't work. The problem is when I create an object of a separate class let us say Movie. It adds the full package name along with the class name in the code area. Something like:

```
new com.example.mycomputer.test.Movie(name,releaseDate);
```

I want the import to be above and only once.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio "Import class" action adds fully qualified name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701789/android-studio-import-class-action-adds-fully-qualified-name)

Answer (score 2):

File --> Settings (in dialog) Code Style --> Java --> Imports (tab) --> "Use fully qualified class names" checkbox

Check this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701789/android-studio-import-class-action-adds-fully-qualified-name)