# Android Studio 3.3.2 use fully qualified name when using "import" action

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm having some trouble with Android Studio 3.3.2 and Kotlin on Mac. Every time I use the "import" action, the fully qualified name is used in-place instead of the import statement. You can see the behavior in this video:

https://i.imgur.com/Mraz7zs.mp4

I already tried the suggestions given in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701789/android-studio-import-class-action-adds-fully-qualified-name) and they don't seem to work. I also tried reinstalling Android Studio and deleting its configuration, but neither worked.

Comment: I haven't used 3.3 yet, but once I accidentally toggled " use fully qualified names" under the import settings for Java and kotlin. Did you check these?

Comment: I have checked, the setting is not toggled

Answer (score 1):

This behavior for importing generated **Data Binding** classes occurs when you try to import a class while the project is not yet built. First click on "**Rebuild project**" and then import the class. Then the import works correctly.

Comment: The issue is also present with other classes, I tried **Rebuild Project** but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this the case with every imported class or only with classes generated by DataBinding (my answer was about the last case)?

Comment: It's not with every imported class but it happens with classes other than the ones generated by the DataBinding utility.